# How to rewrite all non ssl request not containing a phrase?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl, url-rewriting

I have a special problem. I need to rewrite all request which goes to http => https, also, I want to fix the url if its missing www, so therefore I also have a rewrite rule for that.

Now, there is one exception, which should not be rewrited. If the request is for
http://www.mydomain.com/**api2/.../..**

everything under api2 should not be rewrited to https...

Here is my current .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
# Start A2 Switcher Block
# Do not remove or modify this block! Added by PHP Switcher from cPanel to use an alterna$
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-php-5.4.13 .php
</IfModule>
# End A2 Switcher Block
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your code like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule !^api2/ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule !^api2/ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^api2/ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^api2/ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

# Start A2 Switcher Block
# Do not remove or modify this block! Added by PHP Switcher from cPanel to use an alterna$
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-php-5.4.13 .php
</IfModule>
# End A2 Switcher Block
```